# Set window background transparent using a hook

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, winapi, hook

On `Qt Designer` plugin for `Visual Studio`, if you set the `MainWindow` background to `transparent` and preview the window, the background is painted all black:

[image]

I wonder if is possible to set the window background 'transparent' by `hooking` any `WINAPI`?

I hooked `CreateWindowExW` and set the `dwExStyle` to `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, but it still painted black.

What else I could try?

```
HWND WINAPI Hook_CreateWindowExW(DWORD dwExStyle,
    LPCWSTR   lpClassName,
    LPCWSTR   lpWindowName,
    DWORD     dwStyle,
    int       X,
    int       Y,
    int       nWidth,
    int       nHeight,
    HWND      hWndParent,
    HMENU     hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID    lpParam
)
{    
    if (std::wstring_view(lpClassName).find(L"Qt631QWindowIcon") != std::wstring_view::npos)
    {
        dwExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW_Hook(dwExStyle , lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle
        , X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);

    return hWnd;     
}
```

Comment: Google around SetWindowRegion or something like that. (On my phone atm)

Comment: You'll have to explain in respect to *what* the window would need to be transparent (siblings? parent window? whatever is underneath the parent window?) Regardless, `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` probably doesn't do what you think (see [Why isn't my transparent static control transparent?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111028-00/?p=9243) and [Like the cake, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is a lie, or at least not the entire truth](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121217-00/?p=5823)). You'll likely want a layered window instead.